# How to show that $(3,0)$ is a critical point of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2-6x+y^2+9}$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $(3,0)$ is a critical point of f(x,y)=$\sqrt{(x^2-6x+y^2+9)}$.

Ordinarily I would take the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$, set them equal to $0$ and then substitute in the values $(3,0)$. However, there is a big, fat, annoying square root over the entire equation which makes the math a bit tedious for that method.

Are there any easier ways of showing that $(3,0)$ is a critical point of $f(x,y)$?

A friend of mine told me he would give me a hint, so he said the word **"Limits!**" shortly before vanishing in much the same way that our friendship did for giving me such a vague clue without further elaboration.

Help me salvage our friendship! How can I solve this?

EDIT: Oops, the point is $(3,0)$ not $(0,3)$

Comment: The partial derivatives of our unpleasant square root are $0$ at the same places as the ones where the partial derivatives of $x^2-6x+y^2+9$ are $0$. Nicer function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice that you can factor an expression in $x$, you can rewrite

$$f(x, y) = \sqrt{(x - 3)^2 + y^2}$$

Now $(x - 3)^2 + y^2$ is a paraboloid that attains its minimum value at $(3, 0)$, and increases from there - so in a neighbourhood of $(3, 0)$, we have that $f(x, y) > f(3, 0)$ (and rather, $(3, 0)$ is where $f$ attains an absolute minimum).

---

Alternatively, let $g = f^2$, which is a simpler function. Then

$$0 = \partial_x g = 2 f \partial_x f \implies \partial_x f = 0 \text{ or } f = 0$$

So find the critical points of $g$ and the points where $f$ is zero.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help. I should have completed the square in the first place. Okay so without the square root it is a paraboloid, but with the square root it is a cone right? But that doesn't matter because both can follow the same inner form of $(x-h)^2+(y-h)^2$ where $h$ and $k$ determine how far off-centered they will be from the $x$ and $y$ axis origin, respectively. Am I right?

Also, for the second method, isn't that a bit of a gamble for certain problems? Like what if the equation had the cubed root and the critical point was less obvious than this one?

Comment: Okay, the 2nd method is pretty cool: Let $g=f^{2}$ so
$g_x=2x-6=0$ and $g_y=2y=0$. 

Substitute $x=3$ and $y=0$ and thus: $g_x(3,0)=2(3)-6=0$ and $g_y(3,0)=2(0)=0$.